# Same window function in multiple fields in T-SQL: optimization?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, ranking

I am using the very same windowing function in multiple WHEN in a T-SQL SELECT.

```
SELECT 
    ModuleUsage = CASE
        WHEN Operation = 1 and OperationResult=1 and 1 != LAG(operation) OVER(
            PARTITION BY moduleid, clientname
            ORDER BY moduleid, clientname, timestamp, operation
        )
            THEN 1
        WHEN Operation = 2 and OperationResult=3 and 1 = LAG(operation) OVER(
            PARTITION BY moduleid, clientname
            ORDER BY moduleid, clientname, timestamp, operation
        )
            THEN -1
        ELSE 0
    END
    , *
FROM [dbo].[LicencesTracing]
```

Is it evaluated twice or does the query optimizer reuse the result the second time?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can test this for yourself.  Use ` SET STATISTICS` and do a query with just one window call.  Then do your full query with two calls.  Do you see a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could we rewrite the query like below in order to have the function only one time?

```
       -- window function <> 1
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(operation) OVER(PARTITION BY moduleid, clientname ORDER BY moduleid, clientname, timestamp, operation) <> 1

            THEN CASE WHEN Operation = 1 and OperationResult=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

       -- window function = 1
       ELSE

            CASE WHEN Operation = 2 and OperationResult=3 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
       END AS ModuleUsage
      ,*
FROM [dbo].[LicencesTracing];
```

And I thing using `IIF` will simplify the code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(operation) OVER(PARTITION BY moduleid, clientname ORDER BY moduleid, clientname, timestamp, operation) <> 1 
            THEN IIF(Operation = 1 and OperationResult=1, 1, 0)
            ELSE IIF(Operation = 2 and OperationResult=3, -1, 0)
       END AS ModuleUsage
      ,*
FROM [dbo].[LicencesTracing];
```

Comment: IIF will simply the code if they are using 2012+ ;) 
... otherwise they'll just get an error

Comment: @AlanBurstein They are using 2012+ as they are using the `LAG` function ;)

Comment: yes they are. Duh. I need to finish my coffee before commenting further. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if your Window function is being evaluated once or more by looking at the *actual* execution plan (e.g. run the query with "include actual execution plan" turned on).

If you have an index in place to support that window function then it really does not matter much as the operation is inexpensive. A [POC index](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-how-write-t-sql-window-functions-part-3) would be very helpful for this query. The index would look like this:

```
CREATE nonclustered index xxx on dbo.LicencesTracing(moduleid, clientname, timestamp, operation)
INCLUDE <whatever columns you are returning>;
```

You could simplify your query ***and*** force the optimizer to evaluate the Window function by calculating it in a subquery; something like this:
(note that I can't test this...)

```
SELECT ModuleUsage = CASE 
    WHEN Operation = 1 and OperationResult = 1 and lagOp <> 1 THEN  1
    WHEN Operation = 2 and OperationResult = 3 and lagOp =  1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 
END
FROM
(
  SELECT Operation, OperationResult, lagOp =
    LAG(operation) OVER(PARTITION BY moduleid, clientname 
                   ORDER BY moduleid, clientname, timestamp, operation), *
  FROM [dbo].[LicencesTracing]
) sub;
```

Comment: thank you, Alan: you actually gave me a very useful insight in optimization. I marked @gotqn's one as the answer since he solved the question to the roots.